# How do I convert a string to double using input?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to ask a user to input a number in a string type (because that's the only way in C#) and then convert it into a double type.

```
private static string InputDouble(double prompt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:s}: ", prompt);
    return Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

I hope anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: Your method should return `double`

Comment: What is problem? (other than: your method should return double).

Comment: Ohh lol, didn't see that -_- thanks!

Comment: Remember to catch exceptions like `FormatException` for example.

Comment: @ValentinP Which is a really bad appraoch to prevent whrongly formatted input from being parsed. Better would be using `TryParse`. Don´t catch exceptions when you can avoid them in the first place.

Comment: I would not use a try/catch too. `TryParse` is a way to handle exceptions no ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Double's `TryParse` method:

```
public Double? StringToDouble(String input){
    if(Double.TryParse(input, out Double d)) {
        Console.WriteLine("The double value is {0}", d);
        return d;
    }
    else{
       Console.WriteLine("The input string was not in correct format");
   }
   return null;
}
```

The advantage of the `TryParse` method over the `Parse` method is that in case the input is not in correct format, it does not throw any exception and rather it returns a boolean indicating whether the value has been successfully parsed or not.

Comment: The OPs problem is not that the string cannot be parsed. Thus your solution won´t help him/her at all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Although I don't really agree with you, I improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.Parse`:

```
private static double InputDouble(double prompt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:s}: ", prompt);
    return Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```